# How to find out the number of calls to the nCr function

Tags: algorithm

What is the solution of the following recursive equation?

T(n, 0) = 1,
T(n, n) = 1,
T(n, r) = T(n-1, r-1) + T(n-1, r) + 1

I got this while trying to find out the number of calls to the function nCr, in the following definition of nCr

```
int nCr ( int n, int r ) {
  if( n == r || r == 0 ) 
    return 0;
  return nCr( n-1, r-1 ) + nCr( n-1, r );
}
```

Is this recursive equation appropriate for the purpose?

Comment: Maybe this is most appropriate to ask at the math.SE site?

Comment: When the bug is corrected, notice that you're summing a big list of 1's. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your recursive equation is perfectly right (the function you have defined does indeed always return 0, but it is not relevant to the number of calls that are made).

So as to solve it, you should see that it is very close the recursion behind [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), so the value of `T(n,r)` should be related to the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) `C(n,r)`.

If you try to write down the first few lines of this new triangle, you would get:

```
1
1 1
1 3 1
1 5 5 1
1 7 11 7 1
1 9 19 19 9 1
1 11 29 39 29 11 1 
...
```

From this you can either use the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,1,1,1,3,1,1,5,5,1,1,7,11,7,1,1,9,19,19,9,1,1,11,29,39,29,11,1&sort=&language=english&go=Search), or figure out yourself that `T(n,r) = 2 * C(n,r) - 1`.

You can then prove it using induction: if `r = 0` or `r = n`, the relation is true, else

```
T(n,r) = T(n-1,r) + T(n-1,r-1) + 1
       = (2 * C(n-1,r) - 1) + (2 * C(n-1,r-1) - 1) + 1
       = 2 * (C(n-1,r) + C(n-1,r-1)) - 1
       = 2 * C(n,r) - 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks a lot. I guessed that it should be related to pascal's triangle cause of the recurrence relation. But couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: Actually, a more standard trick would be to add `1` to both sides of the relation to get `T(n,r) + 1 = T(n-1,r) + 1 + T(n-1,r-1) + 1` to realize that `T(n,r) + 1` follows the same recurrence relation as the binomial coefficients, and deduce from the initial values (`T(n, 0) + 1 = 2` and `T(n, n) + 1 = 2`) that `T(n,r) + 1 = 2 * C(n,r)`...

Comment: This really clears things up for me. Now when I wrote down a few lines of the triangle, the pattern shows up. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be

```
int nCr ( int n, int r ) {
  if( n == r || r == 0 ) 
    **return 1;**
  return nCr( n-1, r-1 ) + nCr( n-1, r );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track (seriously), except that your function would always return zero. It's trivial to fix though.

Comment: I'm sorry. My bad. It would be the return 1 instead of return 0.

But when trying to find out the number of calls made to this function nCr(n,r), I'm stuck with this recursive equation, which looks familiar but I cannot solve. I also tried drawing the recursion trees to see a pattern, but its being too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial for solving recurrence relations with more than one variable here. The papir pencil method.
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jiang/cs141/recur-tut.txt

If you want to know how many times your function is called, simple add a counter

```
int counter = 0;
int nCr ( int n, int r ) {
  counter++;
  if( n == r || r == 0 ) 
    return 0;
  return nCr( n-1, r-1 ) + nCr( n-1, r );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(As pointed out by others, the return value should be 1.)

The result of the function call is basically nCr(n,r)=1+1+1+...+1+1.
The total number of calls which return 1 is the number of ones in the above sum, nCr(n,r).
The total number of calls which add two values is the number of +'s in the above sum,  nCr(n,r)-1.
Thus the total number of function calls is 2*nCr(n,r)-1.

Comment: Really very nice and easy explanation. Thanks a lot.